# Calling a jQuery Function from code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, code-behind

I want call jQuery Function from code behind because I must send variable for function.
I Used this code in code behind :

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myfunction", "ValidateTB("+ num+ "," + count +");", true);
```

And my function is :

```
 function ValidateTB(num,count) {
    var check = false;
    alert("alert");
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i = i + 1) {
        check = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < count; j = j + 1) {
            var id = "myTextBox" + i + j;
            if ($("input[type='text']").val().length > 0) {
                check = true;
        }
            if (check == false) {
                $("#error").text("error");
                 return false;
        }

        }
    }
     return true;
};
```

Why my function doesn’t work? It sounds my function doesn’t run

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that this function is declared in a `<script>` block which is in the `<head>` section.

Comment: Then this should work. Are you getting some error message in the javascript console? Inspect your DOM to see the corresponding call. Can you see it?

Comment: I haven’t error,What do you mean? 
when I debug my JavaScript function from External Script Debugger in IE, it doesn’t come to my function.

Comment: Inspect the DOM for a call to this function. I wouldn't use Internet Explorer for web development. Take a look at FireBug.

Comment: Of course that there is. You just put a breakpoint in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this.

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myfunction", "return ValidateTB("+ num+ "," + count +");", true);
```

Your jquery function return true or false value, so you have to write "return" when you will call your function.

Comment: I test it, but doesn't show alert that I add in first line of my function

Comment: Did you call your function from "Page_Load" method? If yes then you must have to include it in "!IsPostBack".

Comment: No, I called my function from Button_Click method!

Comment: Try to do some more cases. Add single quote to your arguments.

Answer (score 0):

While calling any jquery code from codebehind make sure, you surround your code with $(document).ready. You need to change your codebehind call to below:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myfunction", "$(document).ready(function(){ValidateTB('"+ num+ "','" + count +"');});", true);
```

Comment: Well it works for me..Are you getting any errors? please check it in browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RegisterStartupScript` instead

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following jquery class "ChangeDate" with some properties and an OnSelect event which will be invoked during selection,then if we want to use this class in codebehind and change it,then one way is to take a stringbuilder and do as follows,

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.ChangeDate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    yearRange: '-100:+100',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    onSelect: function (date) {
        sMsg = sMsg + getErrorMessage('HME0002');
        if (confirm(sMsg) == true) {
            $('.ChangeDate').val('As of ' + date);
            $(this).datepicker("hide");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $('.ChangeDate').val('As of ' + oldD);
            return false;
        }
    }
}); });
```

Taking StringBuilder in codebehind and append to it the function which is required and calling it using RegisterClientScriptBlock as follows

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("$(document).ready(function () {");
            sb.Append("$('.ChangeDate').val('As of " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "');");
            sb.Append("});");
            BuildJSString("KEY", sb.ToString());

    private void BuildJSString(string keyStr, string scriptStr)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), keyStr, scriptStr,true);
    }
```